# Count the appearance of each alphabet in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a code in c++ that take string input from user and arrange the string in alphabetical order. Now I want to extend this code to give me  output like how many times 'a' appears and so on, but I could not extend it. There may be many ways to deal with this problem, but please if anyone can guide me how to deal with this problem using arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << " please enter your charactor " << endl;
    string ch;
    getline(cin, ch);

    int i, step, temp;
    for (step = 0; step<ch.size() - 1; ++step)
        for (i = 0; i<ch.size()- step - 1; ++i)
        {
            tolower(ch[1]);
            if (tolower(ch[i])>tolower(ch[i + 1]))   
            {
                temp = ch[i];
                ch[i] = ch[i + 1];
                ch[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }

    // count the appearance of each letter using array

    cout << " total lenght of your string's charactor is " << ch.length() << endl;

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: You never state what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: Surely this is a `sort` followed by a `find_if_not` for each value and the `distance` between the values.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // you could easily use a vector instead of an array here if you want.  
    int counter[26]={0};
    string my_string = "some letters";

    for(char c : my_string) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            counter[tolower(c)-'a']++;
        }
    }


    // thanks to @James
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    { 
        cout << char('a' + i) << ": " << counter[i] << endl; 
    }
}
```

subtracting `'a'` from a character baselines the letter `'a'` to position 0 in the array.  You can add the letter `'a'` back to the position when printing it back out.

Using the range-based for loop requires c++11, but you can use a traditional for loop instead in the same way.

Technically this only works for languages with 26 or fewer letters in their alphabet...

Comment: I have updated my code but its giving me the integers at output. Kindly hava a look.     int counter[26];

 for (char c : ch) 
 {
  counter[tolower(c) - 'a']++;
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
 {
  cout << counter[i] << endl;
 }

Comment: This code is not counting the alphabets, its giving me garbage value in front of each letter.

Comment: 'counter' needs initialization.

Comment: This has undefined behavior when characters outside [a-zA-Z] are in the input!!

Comment: Using something like `std::map<char, int>` makes it a bit easier.